# Why can't I activate a Google Script to sort a table from a different sheet of the same workbook in Google Sheets

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have the following script to sort a certain range that sits in a sheet called Activity Log:

```
  function SortActivityLog() {
    var activitylog = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Activity Log");
    activitylog.getRange('B3:H999').activate()
    .sort([{column: 7, ascending: false}, {column: 8, ascending: false}]);
  }
```

When I run the script from the same sheet, it works fine.

When I try to run the script from a different sheet, I get the error message `The coordinates of the range are outside the dimensions of the sheet`.

I've tried placing `activitylog.activate()` just before the sort command to force it to go to that sheet first (since it seems to work fine there) but that doesn't help.

Eventually, I want to have this activated by a time trigger.

Can someone help me out, please?

Comment: B to H is only 7 columns, try reducing your column: properties by 1.  And you don't need activate().

Comment: TheWizEd, thanks for the observation, I hadn't noticed that. But that's not it. That part of the script is recorded and it seems the interger reference columnPosition is to the column of the sheet, not the specified range. The script works fine when I am in the same sheet as the specified range. I even tried to extend the range to A3:H999 and it didn't resolve the problem. It still gives the error when the script is activated from a different shhet.

Comment: TheWizEd, I also took activate() out of the sort line and the script now runs, however, it sord the B3:H999 range on the current sheet I'm on and not the activitylog sheet that I'm trying to sort.

Comment: My guess is that the problem is the `.sort` command - it's not chained to any specific sheet, so it works on what ever sheet you run it from. I'd create a variable for the range on activitylog, such as `var range = activitylog.getRange('B3:H999');`. Then re-write the sort as `range.sort([{column: 7, ascending: false}, {column: 8, ascending: false}]);`